# Get Top 3 from a table in Access with SUM

Tags: php, sql, ms-access

I'm trying to get a Top 3 from a table in MS Access with SQL but I can't wrap my head around it.

```
My_table:

ControlPoint / Points /  Date      / ByWho
---------------------------------------------
   FlagA         6      202305    DepartmentA
   FlagB         5      202305    DepartmentA
   FlagC         1      202305    DepartmentA
   FlagA         3      202305    DepartmentA
   FlagD         3      202305    DepartmentA

   FlagA         1      202305    DepartmentB
   FlagA         3      202304    DepartmentA
```

The user chooses a "DepartamentX" and "Date". After that I want to show the top 3 "ControlPoint" according to the SUM of points. So in this case for "Date: 202305" and "DepartmentA" the result would be =
FlagA 9
FlagB 5
FlagD 3

So what is the best way to do this? By sorting as top 3 direct in SQL or make an array in PHP and then sort it? And then how?

I'm using ODBC.

EDIT:
I used the code below to get me all of the rows, now I just need to figure out how to sum the "Points" to correct "ControlPoint" and then sort it by Top 3 somehow.

```
"SELECT ControlPoint,Points FROM My_table WHERE Date = '{$date}' AND ByWho = '{$bywho}'"

while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){
$array = odbc_result_all($result);
}
```

The code above didn't do the trick, still stuck. Safe to say, I'm going insane over this problem, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 3 ControlPoint , SUM(Points) AS TOTAL_POINTS
FROM My_table 
GROUP BY ByWho , Date , ControlPoint
HAVING ByWho ='{$bywho}' AND Date= '{$date}'
ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC
```

Comment: I got some errors but I modified your suggestion to `SELECT TOP 3 ControlPoint , SUM(Points) AS TOTAL_POINTS
FROM My_table
WHERE ByWho = '{$bywho}' AND Date = '{$date}'
GROUP BY ByWho , Date , ControlPoint
ORDER BY SUM(Points) DESC` which works. I still have problem to echo the results in a nice way but that's not relevant to this. Thank You!